# Mouseover on selenium

Tags: selenium

Im trying to do mouse over on this. If i do hover on women, we can see different submenu's. i want to click any of them. 
Below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http:obsessory.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   System.out.println("ok");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/a"));
   WebElement ve      =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"));
   action.moveToElement(we).click(ve).perform();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try building your action like this:

```
  action.moveToElement(we).moveToElement(ve).click(ve).perform();
```

Few general suggestions to your code:
Add chromedriver to system path so that you don't have to use `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver.exe");` in every test. Also use explicit waits instead of implicit waits, and never use thread.sleep in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example clicking one the menu "Woman" and link "Trousers":

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.ignoring(WebDriverException.class);

driver.get("http://obsessory.com/");

// mouse over the main menu "Women"
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('nav')//a[.='Women']"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(menu).perform();

// click the link "Trousers" until succeed
WebElement link = menu.findElement(By.xpath("..//a[.='Trousers']"));
wait.until((WebDriver wd)->{
    link.click();
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If provided answer not works then you can try like move to element, so wait and then click like below.

```
     action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='nav']/li[2]/ul/li/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

generally i will place my mouse pointer out of screen so that these mouse move actions works well.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Good to know kavya.. :)